# WP_query, Como ordenar o meta_query pela ordem de um array?

Tags: array, wordpress, classificação

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde tenho uma apresentação de Baralho.
Tenho um campo que pega o post pelo naipe do tipo `copas` estando dentro da especificação do array `meta_value`, e gostaria que estivesse ordenado exatamente como está no array:

> **array('K','Q','J','10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2')**

,
Mas a ordem que vem é:

> **'10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','J','Q','K'**..

Não sei como fazer, podem me ajudar?

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'copas',
  'posts_per_page' => '12',
  'meta_key' => 'dbt_carta',
  'meta_value' => array('K','Q','J','10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'),
  'compare' => 'LIKE',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'DESC'
);

// A Query
$cartas = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Vale lembrar que eu preciso que seja nesta ordem, pois depois virá outro filtro, nos `$args`, por que as cartas terão um status de Ativo/Inativo, sendo que precisam sempre se manter na ordem do array e não na ordem em que foi postada.

Comment: Feito como orientado 
@AndersonCarlosWoss obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Segue pergunta e resposta publicadas no Stack Exchange:
>
>   *Link para consulta:***
>   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313015/solved-wp-query-args-how-to-sort-letters-and-numbers-within-the-same-ar

---

**PERGUNTA-->**

I'm developing a system where I have a Deck presentation.
I have a field that takes the post by the 'copas' type of card being within the 'meta_value' array specification, and I would like it to be sorted exactly as it is in the array:

> array('K','Q','J','10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'),

But the next order is:

> '10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','J','Q','K'

I do not know how to do it, can you help me?

```
$args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'copas',
                        'posts_per_page' => '12',
                        'meta_key' => 'dbt_carta',
                        'meta_value' => array('K','Q','J','10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'),
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                        'order' => 'DESC'
                    );

                    // A Query
                    $cartas = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Remember that I need it to be in this order, because then another filter will come in $ args, because the cards will have an Active / Inactive status, and they must always remain in the order of the array and not in the order of the post.

---

**RESPOSTA-->**

> It worked perfectly as indicated by @Pat J, I am grateful for
>   everyone's help! **Below the result**

**This is my meta-box-field:**

```
array(
            //Texto referente ao campo | ponto (N)
            'name' => 'Carta',

            //Texto de exemplo
            'desc' => 'Selecione a Carta',

            //SEMPRE MUDE - Nome registrado no Banco de dados
            'id' => $prefix . 'carta',

            //NÃO MUDE 
            'type' => 'select',

            'options' => array('A','K','Q','J','10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2')
        )
```

**This is the part of the code where I look for the post of the letters and I present on the screen:**

```
<ul id="wpbgallery" class="clearfix">

            <?php 
            $contador = 1 ;
            ?>
            <li class="carta-as" style="justify-content: center;">
                <!-- inicio do loop -->
                <?php 
                // Os argumentos
                $args_A = array(
                    'post_type' => 'copas', 
                    'posts_per_page' => '1',
                    'meta_key' => 'dbt_carta',
                    'meta_value' => 'A'
                );

                // A Query
                $carta_as = new WP_Query( $args_A );

                // O Loop
                while ( $carta_as->have_posts() ) : $carta_as->the_post();

                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-gallery="">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail("baralho"); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <!-- fim do loop -->
            </li>
            <br>
            <li class="cartas">
                <!-- inicio do loop -->
                <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'copas',
                    'posts_per_page' => '12',
                    'meta_key' => 'dbt_carta',
                    'meta_value' => array('K','Q','J','10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'),
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                );

                // A Query
                $cartas = new WP_Query( $args );
                usort( $cartas->posts, 'sort_cartas' );

                function sort_cartas( $a, $b ) {
                    $single = true;
                    $a_dbt_carta = get_post_meta( $a->ID, 'dbt_carta', $single );
                    $b_dbt_carta = get_post_meta( $b->ID, 'dbt_carta', $single );
                    // If they're the same, don't worry about sorting.
                    if ( $a_dbt_carta == $b_dbt_carta ) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    // Converts 'K', 'Q', and 'J' to numbers, for easier comparisons.
                    $face_card_numbers = array( 'K' => 13, 'Q' => 12, 'J' => 11 );
                    if ( in_array( $a_dbt_carta, array_keys( $face_card_numbers ) ) ) {
                        $a_dbt_carta = $face_card_numbers[ $a_dbt_carta ];
                    }
                    if ( in_array( $b_dbt_carta, array_keys( $face_card_numbers ) ) ) {
                        $b_dbt_carta = $face_card_numbers[ $b_dbt_carta ];
                    }
                    if ( $a_dbt_carta > $b_dbt_carta ) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    return 1;
                }


                if ($cartas->have_posts()) :  while ($cartas->have_posts()) :  $cartas->the_post(); 
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-gallery="">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail("baralho"); ?>
                    </a>

                    <?php if($contador == 4): ?>

                    </li>
                    <li class="cartas">

                    <?php endif; $contador++;  ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>

                <p class="text-center">Não existe conteúdo aqui!</p>

            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
```

**This is a representation of the result I'm getting, exactly what I wanted (PS: I can not show the print of the original screen since each card has sensitive and restricted data):**
[image]